# How can I keep my python-daemon process running or restart it on fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, python-daemon

I have a python3.9 script I want to have running 24/7. In it, I use [python-daemon](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon) to keep it running like so:

```py
import daemon

with daemon.DaemonContext():
   %%script%%
```

And it works fine but after a few hours or days, it just crashes randomly. I always start it with `sudo` but I can't seem to figure out where to find the log file of the daemon process for debugging. What can I do to ensure logging? How can I keep the script running or auto-restart it after crashing?

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/leonheess/AntiTrackingBot/blob/main/main.py).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to run a script 24/7 in background, the cleanest and easiest way to do it would surely be to create a systemd service.

There are already many descriptions of how to do that, for example [here](https://github.com/torfsen/python-systemd-tutorial).

One of the advantages of `systemd`, in addition to being able to launch a service at startup, is to be able to restart it after failure.

```
Restart=on-failure
```

---

If all you want to do is automatically restart the program after a crash, the easiest method would probably be to use a bash script.

You can use the `until loop`, which is used to execute a given set of commands as long as the given condition evaluates to false.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

until python /path/to/script.py; do
    echo "The program crashed at `date +%H:%M:%S`. Restarting the script..."
done
```

If the command returns a non zero exit-status, then the script is restarted.

Comment: Another feature of `systemd` is that it can prepare everything needed for a daemon process so the program itself does not have to.

Answer (score 5):

I would start with familiarizing myself with those two questions:

- [How to make a Python script run like a service or daemon in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux)
- [Run a python script with supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737493/run-a-python-script-with-supervisor)

Looks like you need a supervisor that will make sure that your script/daemon is still running. You can take a look at [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/running.html).